# Database schema design for large data usage tracking

Tags: oracle, database-design, database-schema

This is design problem I am facing now, I have 90M data records and I have 10K users of these records. I want to design  the schema which should allow me to track the usage of the these 90M records by 10K users.

Current table structures

```
10k User table
--------------
user_id 
first_name 
lastname..

90M data table: 
---------------
record_id
value1 
value2..
```

Current implementation:-
we have below table for usage tracking the problem with is it is not scalable

```
usage_tracking : 
---------------
record_id
user_id
```

If all the users uses all record than this table will have 90M*10K records. What if my users are 100K or more? This table is not scalable.

Use case:
The product sells these 90M records, users are billed based on the usage of these records. we should assume that all users uses all the records

usage_tracking table is like transaction table when the user access the record from UI entry made this table.

Please suggest scalable design  approach to track which is the user has used which record?

Comment: Provide some effort instead of bringing us your own work. Also, this question is completely unrelated to the client technology (in this case, Java).

Comment: I have added current implementation details.

Comment: Ok, now: why is your current approach not scalable?

Comment: Updated sorry for unclear qeuestion.

Comment: Your current reasons are not real reasons for not making your current approach unscalable. You can use table partition and other oracle specific optimizations for your table. And yes, databases can support such quantity of rows in a table, but you would need more hard drive space.

Answer (score 1):

How likely is that all ten thousand users will touch all ninety million records?  How likely is that even one user will touch of all them?  I don't know but you should.  Because without that information you have no chance of doing a decent job of physical design.

The tracking table you have, `(record_id, user_id)`,  is the smallest you can get away with.  There is no smaller structure which can hold the information you want.

So what are your concerns?

Access speed?  Well, build indexes both ways `(record_id, user_id)` (which is your primary key anyway) and `(user_id, record_id)`.  That way you'll touch the table except for the initial insert.

Space?  You could use table and index compression.  Both compound indexes should compress pretty well.  As your table appears to be insert once you might be able to make use of the basic table compression available with the Enterprise Edition license.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/tablecls.htm#CNCPT89138).

---

All this is general, which is all you can get without providing specific use cases.  For instance, if your customer wants to know *when was the last time a user touched a specific record?* then that's a problem.  Also, you have the issue of how you are going to implement the actual tracking (which is another question, in my view).

Comment: Please find use case added to question.

Comment: +1 and you could probably implement the table as an index organised table

Comment: @RobvanWijk - I disagree wrt IOT: I would expect accesses through both USER_ID and RECORD_ID, so there should be two indexes, with each as the leading column.  Last I heard, Oracle's advice was still not to build an index on an IOT.

Comment: I'm curious why Oracle would advice against an extra index on an IOT. Do you have a link?

Comment: @RobvanWijk - Tom discusses IOT and secondary indexes in one of his books but the clearest online thing I could find is on [Use the Index Luke](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/clustering/index-organized-clustered-index).  Although Richard Foote offers slightly more nuanced advice [here](https://richardfoote.wordpress.com/category/index-organized-tables/).